# How to pass datetime in SQL Server query using Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, datetime, pyodbc

I am relatively new here and I will really appreciate your help.

I want to run this SQL query in Python:

```
SELECT datepoint, type_prix_id, prix
FROM XXXXXX
WHERE datepoint BETWEEN '22/07/2020 00:10:00' AND '23/07/2020'  
  AND type_prix_id = 25
```

So I wrote this but I have a problem with the date:

```
#test appel DB

import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import time as tt

connexion = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=XXXXX;'
                      'Database=XXXXX;'
                      'UID=XXXXX;'
                      'PWD=XXXXXX')


cursor = connexion.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM database.dbo.table WHERE datepoint BETWEEN '22/07/2020 00:10:00' AND '23/07/2020' ')
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

This code works when I delete the date parameters, but with it it always fail. I have researched this and I find that I have to pass a parameter for the date but I have no idea how to do this.

I will really appreciate your help guys.

Have a good day !

Comment: Try `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM database.dbo.table WHERE datepoint between '2020-07-22 00:10:00' and '2020-07-23'")`

Comment: Hi Gord, thanks for your answer. But it does not work because it raise me an error, that he cannot transform varchar values in datetime

Comment: I dunno, [this code](https://pastebin.com/hmy60T6E) works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepared query statement through use of parameters and **?** placeholders such as

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM database.dbo.table WHERE [datepoint] BETWEEN ? AND ? ",
               '2020-07-22 00:10:00','2020-07-23')
```

in order to have a SQL Select statement which is clear and safe against SQL injection

***P.S.*** Using Single quotes without escapes surrounded within single quotes is a violation. So , will raise an error.

Comment: Hi Barbaros, thank you very much for your answer. I have tried it but it raise me a new error : pyodbc.Error: ('HYC00', '[HYC00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Optional functionnality non -implemented(0) (SQLBindParameter)')

Comment: Hi @Lehax get rid of `datetime.date` and retry only by using the current literals then.

Comment: I have an error again, it said that he cannot transform varchar in datetime. I think it's because my DB is like this 2020-07-22 00:30:00.000, so i have to set up the hour also no ?

Comment: cursor = connexion.cursor()




cursor.execute("""
               SELECT datepoint, type_prix_id, prix FROM database.dbo.table WHERE datepoint BETWEEN ? AND ?
               """,'2020-07-22 00:10:00','2020-07-23 00:10:00')
for row in cursor:
    print(row)

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved :

```
date_timedeb_str = '2020-07-26 00:10:00'
date_time_obj1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_timedeb_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

date_timefin_str = '2020-07-29 00:10:00'
date_time_obj2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_timefin_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

cursor.execute("""
               SELECT datepoint, type_prix_id, prix FROM database.dbo.table  WHERE datepoint BETWEEN ? AND ? AND type_prix_id = ?
               """,(date_time_obj1),(date_time_obj2),(25))
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```